# I am using tkinter libary making a hangman program but I am getting an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, error-handling

I am making a "hangman" program in python, it follows the same principle as "Hangman", each time you get something wrong it adds something to the stick person, my program works, well until the ending because I am not done yet but the basics are there. The image gets displayed and the user has 8 wrong attempts (this part is where it goes wrong) the image displays and when I was testing with print statements to check variables are working, they would work and the image gets displayed but after it, this error message come forward, and I can't seem to understand why. I'm using python 3.8  and latest version of the tkinter library. Is there anyone who can help me on this?

the error message is:

---

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/James/Desktop/CollegeComputer Science/HangManGUI.py", line 248, in whenPressed
    canvas.config(canvas.create_image(250,250,image=img))
  File "E:\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1637, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "E:\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1622, in _configure
    cnf = _cnfmerge(cnf)
  File "E:\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 109, in _cnfmerge
    for c in _flatten(cnfs):
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

---

The code is:

```
import time
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import random

foodWords = ["CHOCOLATE", "PIZZA", "SAUSAGE", "BEEF", "CHICKEN"]
sportsWords = ["RUGBY", "FOOTBALL", "CRICKET", "BASEBALL", "BASKETBALL"]
placesWords = ["OLDHAM", "MANCHESTER", "LONDON", "BIRMINGHAM", "LEEDS", "BLACKPOOL", "NEWCASTLE"]

usersGuessList = []
usersGuesses = []

def foodgameSettings():
    global secretWordList
    global secretWord
    global genre
    global secretWord
    global baseattempts

    genre = foodWords
    secretWord = random.choice(genre)
    secretWordList = list(secretWord)
    baseattempts = 8
    foodGame()


def sportsgameSettings():
    global secretWordList
    global secretWord
    global genre
    global secretWord
    global baseattempts

    genre = sportsWords
    secretWord = random.choice(genre)
    secretWordList = list(secretWord)
    baseattempts = 8
    sportsGame()

def placesgameSettings():
    global secretWordList
    global secretWord
    global genre
    global secretWord
    global baseattempts

    genre = placesWords
    secretWord = random.choice(genre)
    secretWordList = list(secretWord)
    baseattempts = 8
    placesGame()

def placesGame():
    global genre
    global secretWordList
    global secretWord
    global genre
    global secretWord
    global usersGuessList
    global usersGuesses
    global usersGuessList
    global usersGuesses
    global entry
    global guess
    global placesgamewind
    global label
    global canvas
    global baseattempts
    global status
    global widget

    def printGuessedLetter():
        print("The word is " + ''.join(usersGuessList))

    for n in secretWordList:
        usersGuessList.append('_')
    printGuessedLetter()

    placesgamewind = Tk()
    genrepicker.destroy()
    widget = placesgamewind
    placesgamewind.title("Hangman")
    canvas = Canvas(height="500",width="500")
    canvas.pack()
    Label(placesgamewind,text="Your word:").pack()
    Label(placesgamewind, text="Has this many letters = "+str(len(secretWordList))).pack()
    label = Label(placesgamewind,text=usersGuessList)
    label.pack()
    status = Label(placesgamewind, text="Guess a letter")
    status.pack()
    guess = StringVar(placesgamewind)
    entry = Entry(placesgamewind,   textvariable=guess)
    submitbtn = Button(placesgamewind, command=whenPressed, text="Submit")
    entry.pack()
    submitbtn.pack()

    placesgamewind.mainloop()

def sportsGame():
    global genre
    global secretWordList
    global secretWord
    global genre
    global secretWord
    global usersGuessList
    global usersGuesses
    global usersGuessList
    global usersGuesses
    global entry
    global guess
    global sportsgamewind
    global label
    global canvas
    global baseattempts
    global status
    global widget

    def printGuessedLetter():
        print("The word is " + ''.join(usersGuessList))

    for n in secretWordList:
        usersGuessList.append('_')
    printGuessedLetter()

    sportsgamewind = Tk()
    genrepicker.destroy()
    widget = sportsgamewind
    sportsgamewind.title("Hangman")
    canvas = Canvas(height="500",width="500")
    canvas.pack()
    Label(sportsgamewind,text="Your word:").pack()
    Label(sportsgamewind, text="Has this many letters = "+str(len(secretWordList))).pack()
    label = Label(sportsgamewind,text=usersGuessList)
    label.pack()
    status = Label(sportsgamewind, text="Guess a letter")
    status.pack()
    guess = StringVar(sportsgamewind)
    entry = Entry(sportsgamewind,   textvariable=guess)
    submitbtn = Button(sportsgamewind, command=whenPressed, text="Submit")
    entry.pack()
    submitbtn.pack()

    sportsgamewind.mainloop()

def foodGame():
    global genre
    global secretWordList
    global secretWord
    global genre
    global secretWord
    global usersGuessList
    global usersGuesses
    global usersGuessList
    global usersGuesses
    global entry
    global guess
    global foodgamewind
    global label
    global canvas
    global baseattempts
    global status
    global widget

    def printGuessedLetter():
        print("The word is " + ''.join(usersGuessList))

    for n in secretWordList:
        usersGuessList.append('_')
    printGuessedLetter()

    foodgamewind = Tk()
    genrepicker.destroy()
    widget = foodgamewind
    foodgamewind.title("Hangman")
    canvas = Canvas(height="500",width="500")
    canvas.pack()
    Label(foodgamewind,text="Your word:").pack()
    Label(foodgamewind, text="Has this many letters = "+str(len(secretWordList))).pack()
    label = Label(foodgamewind,text=usersGuessList)
    label.pack()
    status = Label(foodgamewind,text="Guess a letter")
    status.pack()
    guess = StringVar(foodgamewind)
    entry = Entry(foodgamewind, textvariable=guess)
    submitbtn = Button(foodgamewind, command=whenPressed, text="Submit")
    entry.pack()
    submitbtn.pack()

    foodgamewind.mainloop()

def genrePicker():
    global genrepicker

    genrepicker = Tk()
    main.destroy()
    genrepicker.geometry("250x100")
    genrepicker.title("Genre Picker")
    Label(genrepicker,text="Pick your genre...").pack()
    Button(genrepicker,text="Food",command=foodgameSettings).pack()
    Button(genrepicker,text="Sports",comman=sportsgameSettings).pack()
    Button(genrepicker,text="Places",command=placesgameSettings).pack()

    genrepicker.mainloop()

def whenPressed():
    global baseattempts
    global canvas

    userGuess = guess.get().capitalize()
    print(userGuess)

    entry.delete(0,END)
    usersGuesses.append(userGuess)
    if guess in usersGuesses:
        print("You already guess this letter")
    if baseattempts > 0:
        if userGuess in secretWordList:
            print("Nice Guess!")

            for i in range(len(secretWordList)):
                if userGuess == secretWordList[i]:
                    letterIndex = i
                    usersGuessList[letterIndex] = userGuess.upper()

            print("The word is " + ''.join(usersGuessList))

            label.config(text=usersGuessList)

        if usersGuessList == secretWordList:
            print("You won!")
            widget.destroy()

            win= Tk()
            Label(text="You WON!").pack()
            time.sleep(3)
            win.destroy()
            win.mainloop()#
            mainMenu()

        elif userGuess not in secretWordList:
            baseattempts = baseattempts - 1

            print("Try Again!")

            if baseattempts == 7 :
                path = "No Rope Just stand.png"
                img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
                canvas.config(canvas.create_image(250,250,image=img))

            if baseattempts == 6:
                path = "No head just rope.png"
                img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
                canvas.config(canvas.create_image(250, 250, image=img))

            if baseattempts == 5:
                path = "Just Head.png"
                img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
                canvas.config(canvas.create_image(250, 250, image=img))

            if baseattempts == 4:
                path = "No Leg Stick Man.png"
                img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
                canvas.config(canvas.create_image(250, 250, image=img))

            if baseattempts == 3:
                path = "1 Leg Stick Man.png"
                img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
                canvas.config(canvas.create_image(250, 250, image=img))

            if baseattempts == 2:
                path = "2 Legs Stick Man.png"
                img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
                canvas.config(canvas.create_image(250, 250, image=img))

            if baseattempts == 1:
                path = "One Arm 2 Legs Stick Man.png"
                img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
                canvas.config(canvas.create_image(250, 250, image=img))

            if baseattempts == 0:
                path = "Full Stick Man.png"
                img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
                canvas.config(canvas.create_image(250, 250, image=img))
                widget.destroy()


    elif baseattempts == 0 and usersGuessList == secretWord:
        if usersGuessList == secretWord:
            print("You won!")
            widget.destroy()
            win = Tk()
            Label(text="You WON!").pack()
            time.sleep(3)
            win.destroy()
            win.mainloop() 


    if baseattempts == 0 and usersGuessList != secretWord:
        print("You lost, hangman died!")
        widget.destroy()
        win = Tk()
        Label(text="You LOST!").pack()
        time.sleep(3)
        win.destroy()
        win.mainloop()  


    if usersGuessList == secretWord:
        print("You won!")
        win = Tk()
        Label(text="You WON!").pack()
        time.sleep(3)
        win.mainloop()
        win.destroy()
        widget.destroy()


def quit():
    main.destroy()

def mainMenu():
    global main

    main = Tk()
    main.geometry("400x150")
    main.title("Main Menu")

    Label(main,text="Welcome to Hangman would you like to play?").pack()
    Button(main,text="Play",command=genrePicker).pack()
    Button(main,text="Quit", command=quit).pack()

    main.mainloop()
    return main

mainMenu()
```

Comment: What do you think `canvas.config(canvas.create_image(250,250,image=img))` is going to do? Are you trying to configure an item, or the canvas itself? There's a difference between `config` and `itemconfig`.

Comment: I read that it edits tkinter item that you have used so for example canvas = Canavs() and it creates a canvas it updates it but i still get that error message

Comment: I'm trying to display a picture when the button is pressed to a condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I belive you want to do is to update the canvas, so instead of `canvas.config(canvas.create_image(250,250,image=img))` you should do

```
canvas.create_image(250,250,image=img)
canvas.update()
```

there is a tricky here that the img variable is not global, so the image will blink and then will be forgoten. You can fix this by using `global img` before `baseattempts = baseattempts - 1`